# Angular with wordpress - possibilities

Tags: angular, wordpress

I have a question about possibilities integrate wordpress with Angular application.
I would like to have possibility to add simple posts, but also have so more complex, dynamic solutions. I see that I can use wordpress api and display posts in angular application, but is it only solution?

There is no such thing as installing wordpress in an angular application so as to use some functions in this application and write some elements custom? Maybe some packages?

Thanks for your examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to do it without plugin. When it did such thing, I need to create some 'middleware' and not request directly from Angular to Wordpress API(for me, it wasn't secure enough). I created php file that Angular was requesting to and this file was sending request to Wordpress. In case some endpoint need credentials, it was easier to keep it safe.

If you want to use plugin, two options comes to my mind:

> wp-api-angular

and

> ngx-wordpress

Good luck.